# HTML5 Video not playing in IE9

Tags: javascript, html, video

I'm having a problem playing a html5 video in IE9.

Here's how I include the video in the HTML

```
<video id="video-1"></video>
```

I designated the video element on a variable in JS to easily use it on other functions.

```
video1 = document.getElementById("video-1");
```

This is how I assign the video in JS.

```
video1.innerHTML = '<source id="video-1-mp4-src" type="video/mp4" src="' + 'pill.mp4' + '">' + '<source id="video-1-ogg-src" type="video/ogg" src="'+ 'pill.ogg' + '">' + '<source id="video-1-webm-src" type="video/webm" src="' + 'pill.webm' + '">';
```

Also tried this method of assigning the video in JS....

```
video1.innerText = '<source id="video-1-mp4-src" type="video/mp4" src="' + 'pill.mp4' + '">' + '<source id="video-1-ogg-src" type="video/ogg" src="'+ 'pill.ogg' + '">' + '<source id="video-1-webm-src" type="video/webm" src="' + 'pill.webm' + '">';
```

Problem is the video won't load in IE9.... could I be missing something? or is it that the Video tag is not yet supported for IE9?

TIA! :)

Answer (score 1):

I think that's probably related to the [issue](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/jplayer/1MtwR9rPCYY) where you have to declare the video MIME type in the .htaccess file

Comment: so the HTML5 video won't play without that additional setup then? Thanks again. :)

Answer (score 1):

I figured out the solution after a lot of research.

**The `DOCTYPE` of the page must be:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

*(the HTML5 doctype)* in order for IE9 to play HTML5 video. Firefox, Chrome, etc will recognize the video tag even with an XHTML doctype, but IE won't.

Answer (score 0):

Confirm your Browser Mode and Document Mode. Press F12 and verify both the Browser Mode and Document Mode tabs are set to IE9 options.

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me that IE9 can't handle innerHTML for <source> inside <video>.

However it works if you do it the classis way:

```
var video1 = document.getElementById("video-1");
var source = document.createElement('source');  // create source node
source.src = 'pill.mp4';
source.type = "video/mp4";
video1.appendChild(source); // append source node to video node
```

For IE10 and higher you can use "innerHTML".